# Omnetpp, Implicit chunk serialization is disabled to prevent unpredictable performance degradation

Tags: simulation, omnet++, visualizer

I've got the following error message while I run simulation at OMNeT++:

> Implicit chunk serialization is disabled to prevent unpredictable performance degradation (you may consider changing the Chunk::enableImplicitChunkSerialization flag or passing the PF_ALLOW_SERIALIZATION flag to peek) -- in module (inet::visualizer::PhysicalLinkCanvasVisualizer) WirelessB.visualizer.physicalLinkVisualizer (id=23), at t=0.022885250545s, event #11".`

How should I handle it?

Comment: I got the same error running the tutorial. If you found any answer, please deliver here.